# How to get the desired value in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Suppose we have the html code as follows:

```
html = '<div class="dt name">abc</div><div class="name">xyz</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

I want to get the name `xyz`. Then, I write

```
soup.find('div',{'class':'name'})
```

However, it returns `abc`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: ```find_all()``` gives you a list of all that match. Then you'd just access the elements at index 1.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. However, is there any command that directly returns `xyz`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that Beautiful Soup returns the first element that has the class `name` and `div` so the thing is that the first div has class `name` and class `dt` so it selects that div.

So, `div` helps but it still narrows down to 2 `div`s. Next, it returns a array so check the second `div` to use `print(soup('div')[1].text)`. If you want to print all the `div`s use this code:

```
for i in range(len(soup('div')))
    print(soup('div')[i].text)
```

And as pointed out in Ankur Sinha's answer, if you want to select all the `div`s that have only class `name`, then you have to use `select`, like this:

```
soup.select('div[class=name]')[0].get_text()
```

But if there are multiple `div`s that satisfy this property, use this:

```
for i in range(len(soup.select('div[class=name]'))):
    print(soup.select('div[class=name]')[i].get_text())
```

Just to continue Ankur Sinha, when you use `select` or even just `soup()` it forms a array, because there can be multiple items so that's why I used `len()`, to figure out the length of the array. Then I ran a `for` loop on it and then printed the `select` function at `i`  starting from 0.

When you do that, it rather would give a specific `div` instead of a array, and if it gave out a array, calling `get_text()` would produce errors because the array is *NOT* text.

Answer (score 2):

This [blog](https://medium.com/@epicshane/using-beautifulsoup4-to-find-class-exact-match-3e263a95e330) was helpful in doing what you would like, and that is to explicitly find a tag with specific class attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="dt name">abc</div><div class="name">xyz</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag['class'] == ['name'])
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="name">xyz</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without `lambda` also using `select` to find exact class name like this:

```
soup.select("div[class = name]")
```

Will give:

```
[<div class="name">xyz</div>]
```

And if you want the value between tags:

```
soup.select("div[class=name]")[0].get_text()
```

Will give:

```
xyz
```

In case you have ***multiple*** `div` with `class = 'name'`, then you can do:

```
for i in range(len(soup.select("div[class=name]"))):
    print(soup.select("div[class=name]")[i].get_text())
```

---

**Reference:** 
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you, note that it is contingent on the div being the second div item in the html.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="dt name">abc</div><div class="name">xyz</div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')

print(soup('div')[1].text)
```